# Why is this Binary search program giving an error?

Tags: c, binary-search

I wrote the following program for conducting Binary search on an array when the elements are entered in ascending order.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int key,high,low,mid,n,i,a[100];

    clrscr();

    printf("Enter the number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    printf("Enter the key element:");
    scanf("%d",&key);

    low=0;
    mid=n-1;
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    while(low <= high && key != a[mid])
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if (key > a[mid])
            low=mid+1;
        else
            high=mid-1;
    }

    if (a[mid] == key)
        printf("\nKey element is present at position %d",mid+1);
    else
        printf("\nElement not present.");
    getch();
}
```

When I ran the compiled program in Dev C++, I got a 'Memory could not be read' error. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `mid=n-1;` instead of `high=n-1;`.

Answer (score 1):

You failed to initialize `high`, so you're using some garbage in `mid=(low+high)/2;`

You probably want to initialize it along low:

```
low=0;
high=/*whatever*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 mid=n-1;
 mid=(low+high)/2;
```

should probably be:

```
 high = n-1;
 mid = (low+high)/2;
```

Notice how you mistakenly write to  `mid` twice, instead of initializing `high`. Also notice that a proper binary search is quite hard to get right, there are nasty overflow conditions for large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Typo, just replace `mid=n-1;` with `high=n-1;`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on the statement:

```
mid=n-1;
```

This should be changed to:

```
high=n-1;
```

Because you are just including high variable which is not initialized. This also would result in you using garbage in the rest of your code. Mid=n-1 would lead to a logical error.

Always make sure that you initialize the variables.